# Get workflow associated list items

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, splistitem

I have one requirement to get all the list items which has associated with a particular workflow in SharePoint 2013. Like, I have a designer 2013 workflow with name "Test Workflow" which is added in a custom list. Tis workflow associated with around 70 items. In the same list I've added another workflow with name "Test Workflow 2". I need to fetch the ID of all the list items which are associated with the first workflow (all the 70 items ID).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a query can be built filtering

```
taskItem["WorkflowListId"]
taskItem["WorkflowItemId"]
```

as discussed in [this social technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2266d17c-afb9-493a-b2d7-f3eed0f3bf9b/getting-list-item-associated-with-workflow-task-item?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)